# Really struggling with unlist the elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

So i have this matrix which looks like this[image: list matrix]

and i would like to expand all the elements in the list and im trying "unlist", "lappy" and "do.call(rbind)" - but nothing seems to be working for me -it can't be this hard?

Thanks,
Chris

```
dput(y)
structure(list(Data = "Data     : example", Response = "Response variable    : Domestic.Pax", 
    Independent = "Explanatory variables: Domestic.GDP, Domestic.Airfare, Puerto.Rico.Population", 
    Intercept = "(Intercept)            11028544.153 1710074.846   6.449  < .001 ***", 
    X1 = "Domestic.GDP             408667.401   91321.734   4.475  < .001 ***", 
    X2 = "Domestic.Airfare          -4538.832    5527.947  -0.821   0.420", 
    X3 = "Puerto.Rico.Population -2347450.969  642070.743  -3.656   0.001 **", 
    `R-Square` = "R-squared: 0.868,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.851", 
    `F-Statistic` = "F-statistic: 50.514 df(3,23), p.value < .001", 
    n = "Nr obs: 27", market = "dom", version = "1"), .Names = c("Data", 
"Response", "Independent", "Intercept", "X1", "X2", "X3", "R-Square", 
"F-Statistic", "n", "market", "version"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to provide some example data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If it really is a matrix try: `as.vector(mat)`

Comment: What does "expand all the elements in the list" mean? What exactly is the desired output? How to you create such an object in the first place? Seems odd to have so much structured data in a plain character strings.

Comment: Hey MrFlick, so the desired output is for for example rather than X1 = Domestic GDP       408667.401     91321.734    4.475     <.001 ***    Could i get this as 5 different rows of Domestic GDP to <.001 ***  ??

Comment: Do you want something like ```library(stringr); x %>% str_split(pattern = " ")  %>% unlist()``` ?

Comment: Yes rsmith54 - that is exactly what I wanted - Thanks!!